# Problemas com OpenCV - Eyes Cascade and Face Cascade

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, opencv, visão-computacional

Olá! Tudo bem?
Estou fazendo um programa em C++ com OpenCV e ao executar aparece o erro abaixo

Este é o erro que está ocorrendo sem o try-catch

[image: Este é o erro que está ocorrendo sem o try-catch]

Este é o erro que esta ocorrendo com o try-catch

[image: Este é o erro que esta ocorrendo com o try-catch]

```
int detectEye(Mat& im, Mat& tpl, Rect& rect)
{
    vector<cv::Rect> faces, eyes;
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(im, faces, 1.1, 2,
        CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(30, 30));

    for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
    {
        Mat face = im(faces[i]);
        eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale(face, eyes, 1.1, 2,
            CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(20, 20));
        if (eyes.size())
        {
            rect = eyes[0] + Point(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);
            tpl = im(rect);
        }
    }

    return eyes.size();
}
```

Fui debugar e ele lançou a exceção nesse trecho: `face_cascade.detectMultiScale(im, faces, 1.1, 2, CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(30, 30));`

Tela do debug

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qualquer informação adicional é só pedir. Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Eu já tive problemas parecidos quando as bibliotecas do OpenCV não estavam compiladas corretamente conforme a versão do Visual Studio ou da arquitetura do SO (32 ou 64 bits). Pelo log parece que você está usando o VS 2012, mas a tag indica VS 2013. Vc tem certeza que instalou as bibliotecas corretas? Uma forma de verificar se está tudo ok é compilando e rodando alguns dos tutoriais simples do OpenCV.

Comment: Outra coisa que pode estar acontecendo é erro na inicialização do seu cascade. Você não postou o código que inicializa o `face_cascade`, mas lá você referencia um arquivo xml com o cascade treinado (por vc, ou um já disponível no OpenCV). Se esse arquivo não for encontrado, a inicialização retorna um indicativo de erro. E se esse erro for ignorado, pode também gerar exceções no uso mais pra frente (como talvez seja o seu caso). Vale verificar isso também.

Comment: Obrigado! Vou conferir isso e posto uma resposta depois!

Comment: E ai, o problema era esse mesmo ou não? Seria importante ter uma referência aqui, para idealmente auxiliar outras pessoas no futuro, não?

Comment: Verifique se você está carregando a cascata corretamente do disco (face_cascade), pois no trecho de código que você passou não aparece a parte que faz esse procedimento. O erro aponta para isso. Exemplo: face_cascade = CascadeClassifier("/caminho/para/cascata.xml");